# Android emulator plugin, launcher icon is not found

Tags: android, jenkins

I am using Android emulator plugin with `jenkins`. Along with the android application, I also have a java project for uiautomator which is the part of build modules in main pom.

```
The maven goal is : mvn install
```

The uiautomator test is failing at the point where it is trying to assert the presence of application launch icon from "Apps" screen.
Do I have to install the application apk or does the plugin does it automatically as described in the plugin documentation(My plugin version is 2.10 and jennkins version is 1.531)

How do i know that the application is installed in the emulator.
The emulator is started without any problem.

The following is the part of the jenkins log:

```
[android] Starting Android emulator $ /var/lib/jenkins/tools/android-sdk/tools/emulator -no-boot-anim -ports 35965,56985 -prop persist.sys.language=en -prop persist.sys.country=US
-avd hudson_en-US_120_800x1280_android-18_armeabi-v7a -no-snapshot-load -no-snapshot-save -no-window

* daemon not running. starting it now on port 42120 *
* daemon started successfully *

Failed to Initialize backend EGL display

$ /var/lib/jenkins/tools/android-sdk/platform-tools/adb connect localhost:56985 [android] Waiting for emulator to finish booting... $ /var/lib/jenkins/tools/android-sdk/platform-tools/adb -s localhost:56985 shell getprop dev.bootcomplete error: device offline $ /var/lib/jenkins/tools/android-sdk/platform-tools/adb connect localhost:56985

$ /var/lib/jenkins/tools/android-sdk/platform-tools/adb -s localhost:56985 shell getprop dev.bootcomplete error: device offline $ /var/lib/jenkins/tools/android-sdk/platform-tools/adb connect localhost:56985

$ /var/lib/jenkins/tools/android-sdk/platform-tools/adb -s localhost:56985 shell getprop dev.bootcomplete error: device offline $ /var/lib/jenkins/tools/android-sdk/platform-tools/adb disconnect localhost:56985 $ /var/lib/jenkins/tools/android-sdk/platform-tools/adb connect localhost:56985

$ /var/lib/jenkins/tools/android-sdk/platform-tools/adb -s localhost:56985 shell getprop dev.bootcomplete $ /var/lib/jenkins/tools/android-sdk/platform-tools/adb connect localhost:56985

$ /var/lib/jenkins/tools/android-sdk/platform-tools/adb -s localhost:56985 shell getprop dev.bootcomplete $ /var/lib/jenkins/tools/android-sdk/platform-tools/adb connect localhost:56985

$ /var/lib/jenkins/tools/android-sdk/platform-tools/adb -s localhost:56985 shell getprop dev.bootcomplete $ /var/lib/jenkins/tools/android-sdk/platform-tools/adb disconnect localhost:56985 $ /var/lib/jenkins/tools/android-sdk/platform-tools/adb connect localhost:56985

$ /var/lib/jenkins/tools/android-sdk/platform-tools/adb -s localhost:56985 shell getprop dev.bootcomplete $ /var/lib/jenkins/tools/android-sdk/platform-tools/adb connect localhost:56985

$ /var/lib/jenkins/tools/android-sdk/platform-tools/adb -s localhost:56985 shell getprop dev.bootcomplete $ /var/lib/jenkins/tools/android-sdk/platform-tools/adb connect localhost:56985

$ /var/lib/jenkins/tools/android-sdk/platform-tools/adb -s localhost:56985 shell getprop dev.bootcomplete $ /var/lib/jenkins/tools/android-sdk/platform-tools/adb -s localhost:56985 logcat -v time

$ /var/lib/jenkins/tools/android-sdk/platform-tools/adb connect localhost:56985 [android] Attempting to unlock emulator screen $ /var/lib/jenkins/tools/android-sdk/platform-tools/adb -s localhost:56985 shell input keyevent 82

$ /var/lib/jenkins/tools/android-sdk/platform-tools/adb -s localhost:56985 shell input keyevent 4

$ /var/lib/jenkins/tools/android-sdk/platform-tools/adb connect localhost:56985 [android] Emulator is ready for use (took 97 seconds)
```

Answer (score 0):

> Do I have to install the application apk or does the plugin does it automatically as described in the plugin documentation

The [documentation](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Android+Emulator+Plugin) **does not** say that your APK will be automatically installed.

But the plugin *does* provide a build step which will do this for you, if you provide the path to an APK file:

> Under the "Build" section of your job configuration, select "Add build step" and choose "Install Android package".
>
> In the "APK file" field that appears, enter the filename of the APK you wish to install. When a build runs, the APK will be automatically installed after the emulator has started up.

Comment: I was referring to this from the [documentation](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Android+Emulator+Plugin):
**Installing and uninstalling APKs**
Since version 1.9, the plugin can automatically install an APK on the started emulator for you.

Comment: Yes, and if you read the sentence after that one, which I quoted above, it tells you how to do enable APK installation. The plugin can't magically know which file to install, and shouldn't arbitrarily install all APKs it finds in the workspace. That's why the build step described exists.